# Upgrade to MVC 3, now the date picker is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

In my previous version, I used a Date Picker which could default as null as follows;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%:Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" }) %>
```

Now I am using

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" }))
```

And this doesn't work.
When I click on a Date Field, I do not get a popup anymore.

So a date field looks like;

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.contract.GivenDate)
```

This is a DateTime field.
In my _Layout I have;

$(function () {
            $(".datePicker").datepicker({ showOn: 'both', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        });

Also I reference;

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Reminded me to use Firebug in FF. However there are no messages on the console. It is as though the date field and the Template are simply not connecting. However in Firebug the date field is assigned the correct class; <input class="datePicker" id="contract_GivenDate" name="contract.GivenDate" type="text" value="" />

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but your function is inside  $(document).ready()?. If not maybe because it fire before the complete load of the page and your function does not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

Inside `Views\Home\Index.cshtml`:

```
@model MvcApplication10.Models.FooBar
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test DateTime?</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function ()
            {
                $(".datePicker").datepicker({ showOn: 'both', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); 
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GivenDate)
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml`:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" })
@* you'll notice I also removed an extra ) at the end of the last line *@
```

And finally `Models\FooBar.cs`:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public DateTime? GivenDate { get; set; }
}
```

Can you try this out to see if there's any differences?

Comment: Yes, this works in my simplified replica project. I do not know what I am doing differently in my bigger project that would cause it not to work. I shall make incremental changes to the replica until it looks like the original.

Comment: I will award you with the answer. I found working from a simple amp and then making it more like the real one helped me find the answer. The answer was that I was using an old JS library (jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js) which stopped it from working. I would imagine it must be name clashes that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with the jQuery date picker when my input elements don't have an ID (which I see will happen to you here because you aren't specifying a name when calling Html.TextBox), maybe try assigning one? E.g.

```
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker", id = "someUniqueDatePickerId" }))
```

Comment: Tried this but no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using id instead of classes i also included date diff function you can remove it if you want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#StartDate").datepicker();
    $('#EndDate').datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            var diff = dateDiff($('#StartDate').datepicker("getDate"), $('#EndDate').datepicker("getDate"));
            $('#DateDiff').html("Gece Sayısı:" + diff);
        }
    });

    function dateDiff(startDate, endDate) {
        if (endDate && startDate) return (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        return "You must complete both dates!";
    }
});
```

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
        <div id="DateDiff"></div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, although no clues in the question.
The problem was that I was using a javascript library;

jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js

When I disabled it, it worked.
I suspect there are some library name clashes that caused the problem. It worked with jquery-ui-1.8.4.min.js, but now I am using jquery-ui-1.8.10.min.js

Comment: Awarded TheCloudlessSky the correct answer because the approach of starting with a simple app and making it more like the actual app helped me find the solution.